# preg_replace to modify urls coming from curl

Tags: php, url, curl

I need to replace urls in the page taken by curl from another site. My php curl code is;

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init ("http://www.externalwebsite.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('#<div class="headline"[^>]*>(.+?)</div>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}
$html=$matches[1];   
$html = preg_replace('~a href="([a-z,.\-]*)~si', '"', $html); //NEED TO CHANGE THIS                                         

    echo $html;

?>
```

This code working ok until url has any numerical character other than id. This is how html looks like without any preg_replace command.

```
<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
    <div class="title"><a href="http://www.externalwebsite.com/title-of-the-3-page-192345.htm" class="image">
<img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>
```

If I use the preg_replace command above html looks like;

```
<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
    <div class="title"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/read_curl.php?id=3-page-192345" class="image">
<img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>
```

Bu it must be something like this;

```
<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
    <div class="title"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/read_curl.php?id=192345" class="image">
<img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>
```

Only id must remain, all the other stuff must be deleted. Can anybody help me please?

UPDATE: title of the pages are changing dynamically, last 6 digit is the id, and the only thing must be remain in the url.

Comment: Your last two codes are looking identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User PHP regex:

```
/\d{6}/
```

Result:

```
<?php
    $str='<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title"><a href="http://www.externalwebsite.com/title-of-the-3-page-192345.htm" class="image">
    <img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>';
    preg_match("/\d{6}/", $str, $matches);
    $st = $matches[0];

    echo '<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <div class="title"><a href="http://www.externalwebsite.com/read_curl?id='.$st.'" class="image">
    <img src="http://www.externalwebsite.com/d/news/94406.jpg"/></a></div></div>';

    ?>
```

Comment: thank you but "title-of-the-3-page" dynamically changing, I need to clear everything before the id (last 6 digit).

Comment: you should give such descriptions in question - any way wait